Find all continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(z) \leq 1$ for some $z \neq 0$
Find all continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy
$$
f(z) \leq 1 \text{ for some nonzero real number } z
$$
and
$$
f(x)^2 + f(y)^2 + f(x + y)^2 - 2f(x)f(y)f(x + y) = 1
$$
for all real numbers $x$ and $y$
Attempt
$x=y=0$ and let $a=f(0)$ we get $(a-1)^{2} (a+\frac{1}{2})=0$ , so either $a=1$ or $a=-\frac{1}{2}$.
Case-1
Case: $a=-\frac{1}{2}$ by setting $y=-x$ we get :
$$f(x)^{2} + f(-x)^{2} + \frac{1}{4}  + f(x)f(-x)= 1$$hence
$$(\frac{f(x)}{2} + f(-x))^{2} + \frac{3}{4} (f(x)^{2} -1)=0 ~~(A)$$
hence if there exist $a$ such that $f(a)> 1$ we get :
$$f(a)=1$$which is a contradiction from $(A)$ and so $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} :  f(x) \leq 1$
let $y=0$ we get :
$2 f(x)^{2} + \frac{1}{4} -  f(x)^{2} = 1$ and so $ f(x)^{2} =\frac{3}{4}$ so either $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ or $f(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. If there is
$a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a)= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $f(b)=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ then by continuity there $c$ such that $f(c)=0$, and so by $y=c$ we get $ f(x)^{2}+ f(x+c)^{2} = 1$ but $f(x)^{2} + f(x+c)^{2}= \frac{3}{2} \neq 1$ a contradiction.
So in this case the solution are constant functions : $f\equiv C$ with $C\in \{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\}$
Case-2
case $a=1$:
By $y=-x$ we get :
$(f(x)-f(-x))^{2}=0$ and so $f(-x)=-f(x)$ so $f$ is even.
More advance very enjoyable problem.
Here is the follow up from case 2 previously :
We proved $f$ is even and now we are considering $f(0)=1$. Let $s=\inf \{z > 0 | f(z) \leq 1\}$ the set is non-empty by the hypothesis and by a sequence argument and continuity we can classicaly prove that $f(s)=1$.
We consider again two subcases :
Subcase 1: $s\neq 0$
We take $y=s$ we get $(f(x)-f(x+s))^{2}=0$ hence $f(x)=f(x+s)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and so $s$ is a period of $f$. Since $f$ is even it suffice to determine $f$ in the interval $[0,s]$.
For $u\in (0,s)$ take $x=y=\frac{u}{2}$, we get :
$$2f(\frac{u}{2})^{2}+ f(u)^{2} - 2f(\frac{u}{2})^{2} f(u)= 1$$and so
$$2f(\frac{u}{2})^{2} (1-f(u))- (1-f(u)) (1+f(u))=0$$which lead to :
$$(f(u)-1) [f(u)+1 - 2 f(\frac{u}{2})^{2}]=0$$but since $f(u)\neq 1$ by the minimality of $s$.
we get : for all $u \in (0,s)$ that :
$$ f(u)=2 f(\frac{u}{2})^{2} - 1$$
also true for $u=0$.
It feels like $f(x)=\cos(x)$
A weird thing is happening here, Supposing that $s\neq 0$ we get we get that for all $u \in [0,s)$, $f(u)>1$ by the definition of $s$, but then by looking at the set $\{u \in [0,s) | f(u)> 1\}$ if it is not empty, it has a supremum $m\leq s$ and by the same classical argument we can prove that $f(m)=1$, and so if $m  < s$ we can find $t$ such that $m< t < s$ and $f(t) \leq 1$ by the definition of $m$, but this contradict the minimality of $s$. And so $m=s$.
But here things get weird, take $x_{0} \in (0,s)$ then by definition $v=f(x_{0}) > 1$ but since $s$ is a period of $f$ let $N$ such that $x_{0}+Ns > s$ by the definition of $s=m$ we get $f(x_{0}+Ns) \leq 1$ but from periodicity we get : $f(x_{0}+ Ns)=f(x_{0})=v$ so $v>1$ and $v\leq 1$ which is a contradiction.

I guess Case 1 is wrong as $f(a)\ne C$.

(This is not a complete answer.) First of all, in your case $1$, when setting $y = 0$, you forgot a minus sign and your equation for $f$ is actually for all $x$, $2f(x)^2 + \frac{1}{4} + f(x)^2 = 1$ hence $f = \pm \frac{1}{2}$ but since $f(0) = -\frac{1}{2}$, $f = -\frac{1}{2}$. Actually, if you assume that $f = C$ is constant, your original equality becomes $3C^2 - 2C^3 = 1$ which has exactly $2$ solutions, $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$, giving you two "obvious" solutions.
For a more general $f$, take $y = 0$ and any $x$. You obtain,
$$
2(1 - f(0))f(x)^2 + f(0)^2 = 1.
$$
We recover the idea that if $f(0) \neq 1$, then we must have $f$ constant and $f = -\frac{1}{2}$. Assume from now that $f(0) = 1$. The above equation becomes pointless.
As you said, $f$ is even ($f(-x) = f(x)$ and not $-f(x)$ as you wrote, I guess it is a typo) and $s$-periodic if $s > 0$ (which may not be the case). For your last remark, I think you made a mistake about the definition of $\inf$. If $x > s$, there is no reason to believe that $f(x) \leqslant 1$ since $\{x|f(x) \leqslant 1\}$ may not be an interval.
Last remarks : $f = \cos$ is indeed a solution but in this case, $s = 0$. And if $s > 0$, we may assume that $s = 1$ (or $\pi$ if you prefer) by replacing $f$ by $g : x \mapsto f\left(\frac{x}{s}\right)$, which is also solution of the problem. From here, it seems legit to believe that $f$ is periodic whatever is the value of $s$, and then we may assume the period is $1$.
As you wrote it, whenever $f(x) \neq 1$, we have $f(x) = 2f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2 - 1$. The easiest case is actually the case $s = 0$. Assume that $f$ is non constant so $t_0 = \inf\{x \geqslant 0|f(x) < 1\}$ is well defined and $f(t_0) = 1$. If you choose some $t > t_0$ close enough to $t_0$, by definition of $t_0$ and by continuity of $f$, we have $f(t) < 1$ and whenever $0 \leqslant x \leqslant t$, $-1 \leqslant f(x) \leqslant 1$.
From now of, you can use sequence based methods to find $f$. Define the sequence $(u_n(x))$ as $u_n(x) = \arccos\left(f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)\right)$ for some $0 \leqslant x \leqslant t$. Since $\cos \circ \arccos = \mathrm{id}$ on $[-1,1]$, $(u_n(x))$ verifies the induction formula,
$$
u_0(x) = \arccos(f(x)), \qquad \cos(u_n(x)) = 2\cos(u_{n + 1}(x))^2 - 1 = \cos(2u_{n + 1}(x)).
$$
Since both $u_n(x)$ and $u_{n + 1}(x)$ belong to $[0,\pi]$ where $\cos$ is injective, $u_n(x) = 2u_{n + 1}(x)$ i.e. $2^nu_n(x) = u_0(x)$ thus, taking the $\cos$,
$$
f(x) = \cos\left(2^n\arccos\left(f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)\right)\right).
$$
If we assume that $f'(0)$ exists, then by setting $\omega = (\arccos \circ f)'(0)$, the above equality becomes, when $n \rightarrow +\infty$,
$$
f(x) = \cos(\omega x).
$$
This is true for $0 \leqslant x \leqslant t$ but in this case, $t_0 = +\infty$ because $f \leqslant 1$ hence the above equality is true for all $x$. I don't know yet how to get rid of the hypothesis $f'(0)$ exists nor how to handle the  case $s > 0$ (ideally, we can try to prove that $s = 0$), but this enables us to conjecture that all the solutions to this problem are the $x \mapsto \cos(\omega x)$ and $f = -\frac{1}{2}$ (notice that the case $f = 1$ is covered by $f(x) = \cos(\omega x)$ with $\omega = 0$).

The only constant solutions are
$$\boxed{\text{S1 : }f(x)=1\quad\forall x},$$
which indeed fits, and
$$\boxed{\text{S2 : }f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\quad\forall x},$$
which also fits. So, let us from now on look only for non-constant solutions.
Let $P(x,y)$ be the assertion $f(x)^2+f(y)^2+f(x+y)^2-2f(x)f(y)f(x+y)=1$.
Let $A=f^{-1}(\{1\})$ (maybe empty).
Let $U=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ (maybe empty).
$P(x,0)$ implies $(2f(x)^2-1-f(0))(1-f(0))=0$, so $f(0)=1$ (otherwise, $f(x)^2$ is constant, and since continuous, $f(x)$ is constant).
$P(x,-x)$ implies $f(-x)=f(x)$, so $f(x)$ is even.
$P(x,x)$ implies $(f(2x)-f(x)^2)^2=(1-f(x)^2)^2$, and so we have the assertion
$$Q(x) : \text{ either } f(2x)=1, \text{ or } f(2x)=2f(x)^2-1.$$
If $\exists T\ne 0$, $T\in A$, then $P(x,T)$ implies $f(x+T)=f(x)$.
A) If $\exists u$ such that $f(u)>1$, no nonconstant solution.
Writing $P(x,u)$ as $(f(x+u)^2-f(x)f(u))^2=(f(u)^2-1)(f(x)^2-1)$, we get $f(x)^2\ge 1$ $\forall x$, and so, since continuous, $f(x)\ge 1$ $\forall x$.
A-1) $f(x)>1$ $\forall x\ne 0$
If $f(x)=1$ for some $x\ne 0$ (WLOG $x>0$ since $f(x)$ is even):
Let $T=\inf A_{>0}$. $T>0$; otherwise, $T=0$ would imply $f(x)$ is periodic with periods as small as we want and so, since continuous, $f(x)$ would be constant. Since continuous, $f(T)=1$. Clearly, $A=T\mathbb{Z}$.
Since $f(0)=f(T)=1$ and $f(x)>1$ $\forall x\in(0,T)$, there exists $r\in(0,T)$ (global max over $[0,T]$) such that $f(r)=M\ge f(x)$ $\forall x\in[0,T]$.
$M>1$ and, since periodic, $M$ is a global max over $\mathbb{R}$. But $2M^2-1>M$, so $Q(r)$ implies $f(2r)=1$.
$2r\in A$, $r\in(0,T)$, and $A=T\mathbb{Z}$ imply $r=\frac{T}{2}$.
But then, continuity implies that we can find $x<r=\frac{T}{2}$ as near as we want to $r$, so that $f(x)$ is as near as we want to $M$.
Then $Q(x)$ cannot imply $f(2x)=1$ since $2x<T$.
But $Q(x)$ cannot imply $f(2x)=2f(x)^2-1$ since then $f(x)$ being as near as we want to $M$, we'd get $f(2x)>M$, which is impossible.
So no such $T$ exists, and $f(x)>1$ $\forall x\ne 0$.
Q.E.D.
A-2) No solution exists here.
A-1 is in contradiction with "$\exists z\ne 0$ such that $f(z)\le 1$".
Q.E.D.
B) If $f(x)\le 1$ $\forall x$, then $f(x)=\cos(ax)$ for some $a\ne 0$.
Since $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)$ is continuous, there exists $u$ such that $1>f(u)>0$.
Writing $P(x,u)$ as $(f(x+u)^2-f(x)f(u))^2=(1-f(x)^2)(1-f(u)^2)$, we get $f(x)^2\le 1$ $\forall x$, and so $f(x)\in[-1,1]$ $\forall x$.
B-1) $\exists t>0$ such that $f(t)=1$.
Since nonconstant, continuous, and $f(0)=1$, $f(\mathbb{R})$ contains some interval $(a,1)$ for some $a\in(0,1)$.
Trivially, $\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)\in(a,1)$.
Let $u>0$ such that $f(u)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)$.
$Q(u)$ implies either $f(2u)=1$, or $f(2u)=2f(u)^2-1=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{1-n}}\right)$.
Repeating this process, we'll necessarily encounter some $k$ such that $f(2^k u)=1$ (at most $k=n+1$).
Q.E.D.
B-2) $f(x)$ is periodic with minimal period $T>0$ and $f(x)=1$ if and only if $x=nT$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $T=\inf A_{>0}$. $T>0$; otherwise, $T=0$ would imply $f(x)$ is periodic with periods as small as we want and so, since continuous, $f(x)$ would be constant. Since continuous, $f(T)=1$. Clearly, $A=T\mathbb{Z}$.
Q.E.D.
B-3) $\exists u\in(0,\frac{T}{3})$ such that $f(u)=0$.
$f(x)<1$ $\forall x\in(0,T)$ (since $T$ is the smallest positive number such that $f(x)=1$).
So $f\left(\frac{T}{3}\right)\ne 1$ and $f\left(\frac{2T}{3}\right)\ne 1$.
And so $Q\left(\frac{T}{3}\right)$ implies $f\left(\frac{2T}{3}\right)=2f\left(\frac{T}{3}\right)^2-1$.
But $f\left(\frac{2T}{3}\right)=f\left(T-\frac{T}{3}\right)=f\left(-\frac{T}{3}\right)=f\left(\frac{T}{3}\right)$.
And so $f\left(\frac{T}{3}\right)=2f\left(\frac{T}{3}\right)^2-1$, and so $f\left(\frac{T}{3}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}$ (since $f(x)<1$).
So $\exists u\in(0,\frac{T}{3})$ such that $f(u)=0$.
Q.E.D.
B-4) $f\left(\frac{T}{4}\right)=0$ and $f(x)\in(0,1)$ $\forall x\in(0,\frac{T}{4})$.
Let $U=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $V=\inf U_{>0}$.
$V<\frac{T}{3}$ and $f(V)=0$ (continuity: $\inf$ is minimum).
So $Q(V)$ implies $f(2V)=-1$ (since $2V<T$ and so $f(2V)\ne 1$).
So $Q(2V)$ implies $f(4V)=1$.
And so $4V=nT$, and since $V<\frac{T}{3}$, the only solution is $V=\frac{T}{4}$.
Q.E.D.
B-5) $f(x+T)=f(x)$, $f(T-x)=f(x)$, and $f\left(\frac{T}{2}-x\right)=-f(x)$.
The first equation follows from paragraph B-2.
The second is because $f(x)$ is even, so $f(T-x)=f(-x)=f(x)$.
The third: $Q\left(\frac{T}{4}\right)$ implies $f\left(\frac{T}{2}\right)=-1$, and so $P\left(x,\frac{T}{2}-x\right)$ implies $f(\frac T2-x)=-f(x)$
B-6) $f(x) = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi x}{T}\right)$ for some $T > 0$.
Now, since $f(x + T) = f(x)$ and $f\left(\frac{T}{2} - x\right) = -f(x)$, we can examine the general form of $f(x)$. Notice that:

$f(0) = 1$,
$f\left(\frac{T}{2}\right) = -1$,
$f\left(\frac{T}{4}\right) = 0$.

Given these periodic and symmetric properties, $f(x)$ must be of the form $f(x) = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi x}{T}\right)$ for some $T > 0$. This is because the cosine function satisfies all the periodicity and symmetry conditions derived above.
Hence, the general solution for $f(x)$ under the conditions provided is
$$
\boxed{f(x) = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi x}{T}\right)},
$$
where $T > 0$ is a constant.
Summary of All Possible Solutions
After considering all the possible cases and contradictions, the solutions to the functional equation $f(x)^2 + f(y)^2 + f(x+y)^2 - 2f(x)f(y)f(x+y) = 1$ are:

The constant solutions:

$f(x) = 1 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.
$f(x) = -\frac{1}{2} \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.


The non-constant solution (up to a scaling factor):

$f(x) = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi x}{T}\right)$ for some $T > 0$.



These represent all possible functions $f(x)$ that satisfy the given functional equation.
